Can we get rid of monotone property?

Given $f$, $f_{1}$, $f_{2,...}$ are monotone functions on $(a, b) \subset
 \mathbb{R}$ and $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in the Lebesgue measure on
$(a, b)$. Prove that $f_{n}(x) \to f(x)$ at every point $x$ where $f$
is continuous at  $x$.

This is my proof
For $\epsilon > 0$, consider the set
$$B = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x \in (a, b) : |f_k(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \}.$$
We prove that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $x_0 \in B$ and therefore the required result is obtained. Alternatively, we prove that if $x_0 \notin B$, then $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$. Suppose $x_0 \notin B$. Then, there exists an increasing sequence $k_n \to \infty$ such that for every $n$ we have
$$|f_{k_n}(x_0) - f(x_0)| \geq \epsilon.$$
On the other hand, the sequence $\{f_{k_n}\}$ converges to $f$ in measure, so it can be assumed to converge almost everywhere to $f$ on $(a, b)$. Therefore, there exists a set $D \subset (a, b)$ with $\mu_{1}(D) = 0$, and for every $x \in (a, b) \setminus D$, we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_{k_n}(x) = f(x)$. Thus, a sequence $\{x_m\} \subset (a, b)$ can be found such that $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} x_m = x_0$ (by the Weierstrass theorem). Assume that for large enough $n$, $f_{k_n}$ is continuous at $x_0$. Then, for sufficiently large $m$, we have
\begin{align*}
|f(x_m) - f(x_0)| &= |f(x_m) - f_{k_n}(x_m) + f_{k_n}(x_m) - f_{k_n}(x_0) + f_{k_n}(x_0) - f(x_0)| \\
&\geq |f_{k_n}(x_0) - f(x_0)| - |f_{k_n}(x_m) - f_{k_n}(x_0)| - |f(x_m) - f_{k_n}(x_m)| \\
&\geq \tfrac{\epsilon}{3}.
\end{align*}
Thus, $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.
Is this proof correct? And what is the role of monotonicity? It seems that I did not use monotonicity in this solution.

If you did not use monotonicity, your proof is necessarily wrong, as the claim is false without monotonicity. Indeed, the result without monotonicity simply says that convergence in measure implies convergence  everywhere.

There appear to be some issues with the set $B$. For example, the union and intersection both have the same index $n$. For the statement that $x_{0}\not\in B$ implies $f$ is not continuous at $x_{0}$, it would be good if you can either include why this occurs or what assumptions are being used there. Another potential place to look is why you have that $f_{k_{n}}$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ for sufficiently large positive integers $n$. At the moment it doesn't appear clear, at least to me, why that is the case.
